# c# code to find folder which contains a group of files and sub folders

Tags: c#, directory

I would like to find a function to find the folder which contains a group of files and folders. For example, for a collection of files as follows:

```
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\File.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\File2.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\Subfolder1\File.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\File.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\Subfolder3
```

The function would return the folder

```
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder
```

And for the collection

```
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\File.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\File.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\File2.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\Subfolder1
```

The function would return:

```
C:\Users\Simon\Documents
```

In the case where there is no common folder such as:

```
Z:\Backup\File.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\File.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\File2.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\Subfolder1\File.doc
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\File.doc
```

The function would return null. Does anyone have such a function?

Comment: I doubt that there is an existing function. You probably have to implement it yourself

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this a long time ago and came up with this:

```
public string GetCommonPath(string[] paths)
{
    if (paths == null || !paths.Any()) return string.Empty;
    var first = paths.OrderBy(x => x.Length).First();
    var common = first.Substring(0, Enumerable.Range(0, first.Length)
        .Reverse()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => paths.All(line => line.Length > x && line.StartsWith(first.Substring(0, x)))));
    var lastChar = common.LastIndexOf(@"\");
    if (lastChar > -1)
        common = common.Substring(0, lastChar);
    return common;
}
```

Comment: When this function gets a single folder as argument, it takes off the last folder element. Works fine for single file.

Answer (score 0):

This is my long-winded code for doing it, restricted to 40 elements in paths:

```
/// <summary>
    ///  Finds common folder for a string array of file and folder paths. 
    ///  eg for input
    ///         C:\Users\Simon\Documents\File.doc
    ///         C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\File.doc
    ///         C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\File2.doc
    ///         C:\Users\Simon\Documents\TestFolder\Subfolder1
    ///         
    /// Output is
    ///         C:\Users\Simon\Documents
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Selection"> array of paths</param>
    /// <returns>common folder path or null if none</returns>
    private string FindCommonFolder(string[] Selection)
    {

        string[] SplitItem;
        List<string[]> ItemList = new List<string[]>();
        foreach (string Item in Selection)
        {
            string[] ItemElements = new string[40];
            SplitItem = Item.Split('\\');
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string Element in SplitItem)
            {
                ItemElements[i] = Element;
                i++;
            }
            ItemList.Add(ItemElements);
        }

        string sCommonFolder = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 39; i++)
        {
            string Element = ItemList[0][i];

            if (Element != null)
            {
                foreach (string[] ListElements in ItemList)
                {
                    if (ListElements[i] != Element)
                    {
                        if (i == 0) return null;
                        else return sCommonFolder.Substring(0, sCommonFolder.Length - 1);
                    }
                }
                sCommonFolder += Element + '\\';
            }
        }
        string sResult = sCommonFolder.Substring(0, sCommonFolder.Length - 1);
        if(Directory.Exists(sResult )) return sResult;
        else return Path.GetDirectoryName(sResult);

    }
```